Getting JSESSIONID Error for cookie validation 302 Response
INFO: A cookie header was received [jsessionid={"name":"JSESSIONID","
value":"8C7D5993B59A9521832CED9AE0E6B6DC",
"comment":null,"expiryDate":null,
"domain":null,"path":"/rxx/v1","secured":true,
"httpOnly":true,"version":-1,"maxAge":-1,
"sameSite":null}]
that contained an invalid cookie. That cookie will be ignored.
Getting the above error when we validating session cookie when using internal spring boot redirect

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
